# Show first instance of number in SQL. Distinct, Inner Join and Join not quite doing the trick

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

What I'm trying to do is only show the first instance of a `sonumber` when there are multiple instances of `solinenumber`. I have tried using `distinct...group by`, `inner join` and `join` without any success. I'm obviously missing something here because I get the following results no matter how I do it:

```
sonumber | solinenumber
-----------------------
00316510 | 0090
-----------------------
00316510 | 0100
-----------------------
00316510 | 0160
-----------------------
00316510 | 0170
```

The code I currently am using is as follows. I am able to post how I used `Distinct...group by`, `inner join`, and `join` if it is necessary

```
Select  so.sonumber, 
        sol.SOLineNumber

From    tblsoso so, 
        tblsoSOLine sol,
        tblsosolinerep tlr

where   so.SONumber = '00316510' AND
        sol.SONumber = so.SONumber AND
        tlr.sonumber = so.sonumber AND
        so.status ='Open'AND 
        so.Status = sol.Status AND
        tlr.SOLineNumber = sol.SOLineNumber
```

Comment: Why are you using implicit joins, rather the the explicit `JOIN` notation from ANSI-92?

Comment: Your example suggests that one row in `so` joins to many rows in `sol`.  Which row from `sol` do you want?  You mention "first", do you mean "the row with lowest value in `solinenumber`"?  If so, would using `MIN(solinenumber)` be sufficient, or would you also want other fields from the `sol` table to be included?

Comment: Please read [Tips for asking a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2835541).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DISTINCT` will return all distinct, unique, rows.  Since all of the rows are unique (seemingly, from your example) this will return all rows.  This will do the same thing as `GROUP BY all_columns_here`.

`INNER JOIN` and `JOIN` are the same thing.  It's worth reading up on joins if you're new to SQL.

What you probably want is `MIN()` with a `GROUP BY`.  This will return only the row with the minimum `solinenumber`:

```
Select  so.sonumber, 
        MIN(sol.SOLineNumber)

From    tblsoso so, 
        tblsoSOLine sol,
        tblsosolinerep tlr

where   so.SONumber = '00316510' AND
        sol.SONumber = so.SONumber AND
        tlr.sonumber = so.sonumber AND
        so.status ='Open'AND 
        so.Status = sol.Status AND
        tlr.SOLineNumber = sol.SOLineNumber

GROUP BY so.sonumber
```

Though you should use explicit join syntax like so:

```
SELECT     so.sonumber, 
           MIN(sol.SOLineNumber)

FROM       tblsoso so
INNER JOIN tblsoSOLine sol ON  sol.SONumber = so.SONumber 
                           AND so.Status = sol.Status
INNER JOIN tblsosolinerep tlr ON  tlr.sonumber = so.sonumber 
                              AND tlr.SOLineNumber = sol.SOLineNumber

WHERE      so.SONumber = '00316510'
AND        so.status ='Open'

GROUP BY   so.sonumber
```

This is the standard syntax, and it is much easier to read.  Especially when you get into using different joins, or large amounts of them.

Comment: I knew it had to have been something simple I was missing. Your first example with MIN() and the group by is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Rick - Seriously, use the *second* query.  The syntax you are using was replaced in 1992, over two decades ago, and is now deprecated on many systems *because it doesn't always work correctly*.  Not to mention that it is harder to read and maintain, easier to make mistakes, and, when I'm hiring, any candidate using this syntax is immediately put behind the candidates that use `JOIN`s.  There's a lot online *(and on SO)* that expounds similar views.

Answer (score 1):

Untested

```
;with cteFirst as (
Select  so.sonumber, 
       ,sol.SOLineNumber
       ,RowNr=Row_Number() over (Partition By so.sonumber order by sol.SOLineNumber) 
From    tblsoso so, 
        tblsoSOLine sol,
        tblsosolinerep tlr

where   so.SONumber = '00316510' AND
        sol.SONumber = so.SONumber AND
        tlr.sonumber = so.sonumber AND
        so.status ='Open'AND 
        so.Status = sol.Status AND
        tlr.SOLineNumber = sol.SOLineNumber
    )
    Select * from cteFirst where RowNr=1
```